# Do CSS 3 animations/the HTML5 <details> tag use JavaScript behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, css

In Chrome the following HTML5 will give you a collapsible content area:

```
 <details>
        <summary>Other resources</summary>
            <ul>
                <li>first thing</li>
                <li>second thing</li>
                <li>third thing</li>
            </ul>

    </details>
```

Previously, we would use some JavaScript to get this done.  Are little tricks like this and some of the CSS3 animations using JavaSCript behind the scenes?

Answer (score 4):

Browser vendors *might* implement such things with JavaScript but could use any language and are as likely (or more likely) to use the programming language that they use for most of the browser code as they are to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Magic.

It's an element that browser UI handles. `<select>` is a much more familiar element that has special behaviour handled by the browser (in particular, check out how it works on a mobile device, pretty useful!) No trickery here, just native implementation.